# Is lottery haram if I don't lose anything?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

Say for instance, I found a lottery ticket on the ground, would it be haram if I used it? Because right now, I'm using a rewards website that gives me surveys to fill, and rewards me points which I can redeem for cash, and there is this sweepstakes that’s going on and if you spend some points, then they will place you as an entry. Is this haram, even if I’m not losing a single penny?

Comment: Two questions in one. Providing a service and getting paid for it (points/cash) - a job is not the same as finding a lottery ticket. I advise you remove that part.

Comment: I agree with @AmericanMuslim.  "Because right now, I'm using a rewards website that gives me surveys to fill, and rewards me points which I can redeem for cash" This wouldn't be counted as lottery.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly speaking, generally, the response would be yeah if this sort of lottery is counted as a kind of the gambling. Then, it is a haram act even though you don’t lose anything. Of course this matter could be surveyed from different aspects, but as a significant one, let’s see why Qomar or gambling is called Myser  (میسر) too?

It is called like that since somebody (one side) obtains the money or the property of another one easily. Accordingly, as a reason, it is haram even though you don’t lose anything. (Since somebody else will lose his/her money easily and actually without any remarkable attempt. Besides, it is declared that playing with gambling instruments would be haram as well, even you don’t win or lose, since totally Qomar is haram based on Quran and narrations.

---

**References:** (As 2 Shi'i (Shia) sites)

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=182658)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa21629)

Comment: Something good to add as a reason why it still is haram whether he doesn't lose anything would be the rule "innama al'amalo bi niyyat"

Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab:

I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for."